# Prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-(i+j)}}{i+j+1}=2.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I could do this double sum 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-(i+j)}}{i+j+1}=2.$$
by making  the summand separable in $i$ and $j$. I hope that you will find it interesting to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure the limits and indexes are correct? What is $j$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote the sum as $S$, use the integral representation of reciprocal: $\frac{1}{x}=\int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1 } dt.$

Write $S= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 ~(t/2)^{i+j} dt = \int_0^1 ~
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}  ~(t/2)^{i+j} dt=  \int_0^1 ~
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ~(t/2)^{k}\right)^2 dt= \int_0^1 ~ \frac{4}{(2-t)^2} dt=2$